# Área de un cluster con DBSCAN

Tags: python

tengo una serie de coordenadas X e Y de unos puntos repartidos por un espacio, y quiero ver si estos puntos forman agrupaciones (clusters) en dicho espacio.

Estas coordenadas las tengo como un array de numpy donde X es la primera columna y Y la segunda; un ejemplo:

```
ch1_data[0:5]
```

[[ 11743.   17707.7]
 [ 15850.9  16474. ]
 [ 21205.1  17580.2]
 [ 11763.2  17712.5]
 [ 14094.9  16369.7]]

Y las proceso con el algoritmo DBSCAN del módulo sklearn.cluster. El código es algo así:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

db1 = DBSCAN(eps=20, min_samples=2, metric='euclidean').fit(ch1_data)
db1_labels = db1.labels_
db1n_clusters_ = len(set(db1_labels)) - (1 if -1 in db1_labels else 0)
print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % db1n_clusters_)
labels_ch1 = db1.labels_
ch1_counts = np.bincount(labels_ch1[labels_ch1>=0])
print('Number of particles per cluster:', ch1_counts)
```

¿Habría alguna forma de conocer el área de los clusters?

Muchas gracias.